# What is the difference between " to smoke" and " for smoking"?

Tags: grammar

I met a sentence like "I stopped to smoke" more often than " I stopped for smoking".
Is there any reason why we use " I stopped to smoke " more often?
And What is the difference between the two sentence in meaning?(What is the reason why we should use "to infinite" in sentence like this?)
I want to know the exact reason why. Help me!

Comment: For some reasons Asians, particularly South Asians (i.e. Indians) gravitate towards the present progressive ("*for smoking*") which native speakers eschew in these contexts. I don't know why - maybe, grammatically speaking, the progressive is more common in their native languages?

Answer (score 3):

(Firstly, **I stopped for smoking**  is not something that native speakers of English are likely to say).

> I stopped to smoke

This implies "I stopped in order to smoke", where the use of *to + infinitive* indicates an intention:

> In this case **to** has the same meaning as **in order to** or **so as to**.
>   Examples
>   She came to collect her pay cheque.
>
> The three bears went to find firewood.
>
> I am calling to ask you about dad.
>
> Your sister has gone to finish her homework.

This is from *[edufind](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/infinitive/)*, where there is more about uses of the infinitive.

So you could use **I stopped to smoke** if you were say, walking along, stopped walking, stood still and then had a cigarette.

However, if you want to say that you **do not smoke any more**, you must say:

> I stopped **smoking**

In this case the verb is followed by a gerund. In English, we stop *a thing*, so "stop" has to be followed by a noun, or the noun form (gerund) of another verb. [Here is a link (*edufind again*](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/verbs-followed-gerunds/)) to a list of common verbs which are followed by a gerund (you will see that *stop* is listed).

Answer (score -1):

"I stopped smoking" means that you were smoking, but for some reason you stopped it. For example, "I stopped smoking when my mom entered my room." Where as, "I stopped to smoke" means that you were going somewhere and stopped, so that you could smoke. For example, "I stopped to smoke on my way back home."

Comment: This is an ELL explanation, and does not actually address the question.