# Why do native speakers often use delexical structures?

Tags: word-choice

I am aware that native speakers use

"I made a decision" more often than " I decided."

and

"I took a walk." more often than "I walked."

Why do native speakers use such structures?

Comment: It sounds better.

Comment: They hear it so many times that it just sticks to their tongues.

Comment: Those aren't "phrasal verbs" (not even 'long" ones). Though if there weren't already a different construction with the same name, 'phrasal verb" would do for this. The literature on this phenomenon tends to call it "verbal extensions" using "small verbs" (like _make, give, take, do_) and nominalizing the verb as an object. As for why people do it, there are several reasons: (1) it gives the speaker a little more time to decide what to say next; (2) it gives the speaker the option of modifying a noun object with an adjective or relative clause, instead of having to modify a verb.

Comment: Here is what phrasal verbs are: https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=phrasal+verb+definition

Comment: As John Lawler mentioned, it makes it possible to modify what would otherwise be a verb.  Consider "I took a long walk." With a bare verb, you have the choice of "I walked longly." (non-idiomatic) or "I walked for a long {distance/time}." (not as _concise_ as my first phrasing above—although one could argue it is more _precise_).

Comment: Question 47 and [still this user does not accept an answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/261745/what-is-the-difference-between-to-smoke-and-for-smoking#comment574718_261745) (the green checkmark) .

Answer (score 4):

[eoisabi.org](http://www.eoisabi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/delexical-verbs1.pdf) gives the following reasons [reformatted]:

> • Delexical structures are very common in current English. Although
>   the total number of delexical verbs is small, they include some of the
>   very commonest words in the language (give / have / take / make / do /
>   hold / keep / set ...) Delexical structures contribute to the
>   impression of fluency in English given by a foreign user.
>
> • In many cases, there is a verb which has a similar meaning to the
>   meaning of the delexical structure. For example, the verb 'look' means
>   almost the same as 'have a look'.
>
> When the word is a verb, as in 'I looked round the room', you are
>   focusing on the action of looking. When you use the word as a noun in
>   a delexical structure, you are naming an event, something which is
>   complete. This structure often seems to be preferred to a structure in
>   which the verb has greater prominence.
>
> • One difference in meaning between using a delexical structure and a
>   verb with a similar meaning is that the delexical structure can give
>   the impression that the event you are describing is brief. For
>   example,
>
> *She gave a giggle*
>
> suggests that there was only one quick giggle, whereas
>
> *She giggled*
>
> does not suggest that the event was brief.
>
> • Another reason for choosing a delexical structure is that you can
>   add further details about the event by using adjectives in front of
>   the noun, rather than by using adverbs. It is more common, for
>   example, to say
>
> *He gave a quick furtive glance round the room*
>
> than to say
>
> *He glanced quickly and furtively round the room*,
>
> which is felt to be rather clumsy and unnatural. Here's another
>   example:
>
> *He made a sincere personal appeal to the Committee.*

I'd add that a major factor is that the non-deverbal 'alternative' may sound stilted or rarefied:

*I bathed, and then drank a coffee. Then I walked.*

or even ungrammatical

[*; BrE at least]*He stopped to photograph.*

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing the term "phrasal verb" with some other concept. A phrasal verb is typically a verb that is combined with a specific preposition (or a particle) that creates a specific meaning.

Your example of "made a..." doesn't create a new definition or meaning. I could very well say "made a cake" or "made the decision" and it has the same meaning, to make/finish/do + something. However, if I said, "ran into [somebody]" this could create specific meaning other than the obvious idea of physically smashing into somebody; it could, and would more probably, mean that you randomly saw somebody that you haven't seen in a long time.