# What's the difference between "looked" and "had a look", which uses a delexical verb?

Tags: verbs, differences, collocation, delexical-verbs

What's the difference between these?

a. I  had a look around the room.

and

b. I looked around the room.

Comment: I've never met the phrase _delexical verb_. But the answer is, you don't have to use it - and, given the unpredictability of which verbs customarily get nouned, it will be hard. You just need to be able to recognise it when it comes up.

Comment: I think we usually use the term 'light' verb.

Comment: I, too, had to look up what delexical verbs are. The term seems to refer to verb phrases such as _have a meal, take a bath_ where the verb is only given its meaning by the noun it is attached to. You just have to learn these phrases, as they are in common use.

Comment: They are called light verbs because they are semantically light in the sense that their contribution to the meaning of the predication is relatively small in comparison with that of their complements, cf. "She gave him a kiss", which has the syntactically simpler alternant "She kissed him", which does not contain a light verb. The main semantic content is located not in the light verb but in the noun functioning as head of  the direct object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do native speakers often use delexical structures?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/261898/why-do-native-speakers-often-use-delexical-structures) 'I bathed, and then drank a coffee. Then I walked in the park' sounds unnatural, stilted.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But let me ask my question in another way:

Comment: These are subtly different. The first demands a reasonably thorough inspection; it is in a terser, businesslike style. Used in a detective novel, perhaps. The second could be more incidental, desultory (though it _may_ have the same meaning as the first). It's in a less informal register. //// With 'I had/took a bath' v 'I bathed', there is no/negligible difference in meaning, but hardly anybody uses the second variant nowadays.

Comment: You can modify the verb kiss with all sorts of adverbs and noun version with all sorts of adjectives. They can end up being pretty much the same. She kissed him squarely on the lips. She gave him a kiss square on the lips. I see no meaningful difference.

Answer (score 1):

In "I had a look around the room," *had* is a **light verb**, one whose contribution in terms of meaning is small in comparison with that of its complement *look*; typically this complement is associated with an ordinary verb, and there is an alternant that uses that verb, in this case "I looked around the room"  ([Huddleston & Pullum (2002)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cambridge_Grammar_of_the_English_Language), p. 290-291). Generally, using a light verb "yield[s] a significant increase in syntactic versatility over that of the associated verb construction," since it allows "a greater range of elaboration by modifiers and determiners" (*ibid.*, p. 291). Moreover, in cases like this one, the use of the indefinite article results in a change in meaning; "I had a look around the room" suggests a single, short event, whereas "I looked around the room" does not necessarily do so; compare "She gave him a kiss" with "She kissed him"  (*ibid.*, p. 290-291).

Comment: I had a **quick look** around the room. I **looked quickly** around the room. Same thing really. I don't see amu real difference in meaning. Those guys seem not to like other formulations based on how the language actually works.

Comment: @Lambie Note what I said: "I looked around the room" does not **necessarily** suggest a single, short event, whereas "I had a look around the room" does. Compare: "I looked around the room for hours" sounds fine, but "I had a look around the room for hours" sounds quite odd, at least to me.

Comment: I had a long, slow look around the room. This game can be played forever.